# Firebase realtime database uid key restrictions

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I wish to verify that a Firebase realtime database key is valid. What restrictions and/or rules applies to realtime database uid keys? I have not found any documentation that points out invalid characters, max and min length etc.

Kind regards /K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data):

> If you create your own keys, they must be UTF-8 encoded, can be a maximum of 768 bytes, and cannot contain ., $, #, [, ], /, or ASCII control characters 0-31 or 127. You cannot use ASCII control characters in the values themselves, either.

Comment: Many thanks! Are the same rules true for Firebase generated unique keys? /K

Comment: Yeah, The docs indeed are a bit weirdly phrased. There's nothing special about push keys as far as allowed characters are concerned.